# How to prevent multiple authentication calls via WebClient

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

The following code will fetch 20 devices and will consume some data from an online service.

In order to use the online service the WebClient need to get access token (authorization-grant-type=client_credentials)

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.web.client-id=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.web.client-secret=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.web.scope=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.web.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.web.token-uri=https://xxxx
```

**Config:**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Autowired
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

@Bean
public WebClient webClient(ExchangeFilterFunction getOAuth2FilterFunction) {
    logger.info("** start webClient **");
    
    return WebClient.builder().filter(getOAuth2FilterFunction).build();
}

@Bean
public ExchangeFilterFunction getOAuth2FilterFunction(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    logger.info("** start getOAuth2FilterFunction **");
    
    InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(new ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider());

    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2FilterFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2FilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("web");
    return oauth2FilterFunction;
}

@Bean
public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations() {
    logger.info("** start clientRegistrations **");
    
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("web");
    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
}
```

**WebClient:**

```
private void getData(List<Device> initlist) {
    logger.info("** start getDeviceData **");
    
    List<Mono<DeviceDto>> jsonDeviceList = initlist.stream()
            .map(device -> webClient.post().uri(infoUri)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .body(Mono.just(device.getMacAddress()),String.class)
                    .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("web"))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(DeviceDto.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Flux<DeviceDto> mergedMonos = Flux.fromIterable(jsonDeviceList).flatMapSequential(Function.identity());
    mergedMonos.map(device -> mapper.valueToTree(device)).collectList().subscribe(list -> {
        generateCsv(list);
    });
}
```

The problem is that for each service request there will be an equivalent access token request from the authentication server. So for all 20 devices in the list the WebClient will request access token 20 times.

How can I change this to have only one call rather then 20 ?

Thank you

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I can see via DEBUG mode that there are 20 auth calls

Comment: and that was not my question, my question was, what code have you written to try to solve the problem.

Comment: whatever you see in the post

Comment: you have written a interception filter that will intercept each request call an oauth server. ofc it will do one request for each. if you dont want to, then do one request first, and then your 20 requests.... using a regular webclient.

Comment: Thank you Toerktumlare. Can you please share some code example.

Comment: No i cant, good luck

Answer (score 0):

What @Toerktumlare said is right. If you want to call oauth server once, you just need to cache the access_token in memory or redis at first request and then use the same access_token before it is expired.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken())
        .build();

private String getAccessToken() {
    // get access_token from redis
    // if expiring, it will return null
    String access_token = (String) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("access_token");
    if (null != access_token) {
        return access_token;
    }
    // get access_token from oauth server again and cache it into redis
    return getAccessTokenFromOauthServer();
}
```

Comment: How can I get the token ?

Comment: Getting the token from your oauth server.

Comment: Thank you Holinc, Yes the process of getting the token from the server and sending a successful request with the token via WebClient is working well. But how can I print the token ? I need the token in order to add it via another function to the request.